# Twitter search limit has never been this strict

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I know that Twitter search API has it's own limitations and returns much less search results rather than the actual results but I was searching through a popular hashtag and it only returns 60 result which is not acceptable at all!

here is my code in which I've used [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) module.

```
results = {}
last_id = None
count = 0
while(len(results.keys()) != min_count):
    if(last_id):
        tmp_results = self.api.search(q="#mentionsomeoneimportantforyou", count=100, max_id=last_id)
    else:
        tmp_results = self.api.search(q=#mentionsomeoneimportantforyou, count=100)
    count += len(tmp_results['statuses'])
    print("new len:  ", count)
    last_id = get_max_id(tmp_results)


def get_max_id(results):
    next_results_url_params = results['search_metadata']['next_results']
    next_max_id = next_results_url_params.split('max_id=')[1].split('&')[0]
    return next_max_id
```

Is there anything run with this code? It not, isn't 60 of many a joke?

Answer (score 0):

The [twython docs](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/special_functions.html#cursor) suggest not doing it that way, using the cursor approach instead:

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
                  OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

results = twitter.cursor(twitter.search, q='python')
count = 0
for result in results:
    print result['id_str']
    count += 1
print count
```

prints:

```
... many here ...
561918886380322816
561918859050229761
561919180480737282
561919151162130434
561919142450581504
561919113812246529
561919107134922753
561919103867559938
561919077481218049
561918994454556672
561918971755372546
561918962381127680
561918948288258048
561918911751655425
561918904126042112
561918886380322816
561918859050229761
645
```

Comment: No, test q='#mentionsomeoneimportantforyou' and it again returns only 60 of many.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. According to [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) Twitter doesn't return tweets older than a week through search api.